# Intermittent SQL Azure login / network errors

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database

We recently moved to Azure and started experiencing loads and loads of failures with our Azure SQL database instance (S0). Following [Microsoft Azure guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx), we've changed our code to make it fault tolerant by configuring our connector (Entity Framework) to retry on intermittent Azure errors:

```
public class SqlAzureConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SqlAzureConfiguration() {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy()); 
    }
}
```

This did help a lot and largely got rid of time out errors. This is being said, we are still facing a couple of **random** SQL errors at **random times in a week** which we have no clue how to fix (we look at a lot of duplicate questions here on SO with no luck)

1. `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found`
2. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'MyUserName'.`

Does anyone know how to fix these issues or at least overcome them?

Comment: Do you have the same kind of error using another database size ? (S1 or P1) ? Do you have any logs on the Azure portal ? You could also create your own `IDbExecutionStrategy` that will inherits from `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` and wait few ms before retrying

Comment: The logs unfortunately don't tell much. All is there is a stack trace showing where my code fails with the exceptions mentioned in the question. I haven't tried other sizes as the S0 instance looks pretty much stable where the DTU is way below the limit (10 DTUs)

Comment: Have you looked at the concurrency limits?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-resource-limits/

Comment: can you connect to your database over the visual studio SQl SErver object explorer?

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the pointer. I will take a look and will let you know. This is being said, the error occurs at a point where activity is at its lowest during the day so i doubt this is a concurrent connexions issue

Comment: @tire001 Yes, i can connect to the db usine object explorer but i cant confirm if this is the case when this behavior occurs as it is totally random and happens at different times in a week

Comment: Not always related.  @GETah If you have had loads of open connections that are not closed but can't be used you may hit the limit regardless.  This is along those lines.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731746/ado-net-connection-pool-concurency-issue-with-sql-azure-or-how-we-cannot-scale-o